# IValidateObject how to Clear/Reset ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class that implements IValidateObject. My business rule is satisfied after I do some additional work in a controller's action. The problem I have is the ModelState.IsValid is still false. I am trying to find how to have it reset or rerun so the ModelState is updated. I tried TryUpdateModel, that trigged the Validate method and if I step through my rule is now valid, but ModelState.IsValid is still false (and I can see it is still complaining about the same rule).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
    {
        //ModelState.IsValid is False at this point

        //model.Do More Stuff To Satisfy IValidateObject rule. At this point all my rules are valid

        TryUpdateModel(model); // <-- If run TryUpdateModel and step through, I can see my rule is valid 

        if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is still False
        {
            //Save
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I ended up calling

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

[HttpPost]

```
   public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
   {   
        //model.Do More Stuff To Satisfy IValidateObject rule. At this point all my rules are valid
        ModelState.Clear();

        TryUpdateModel(model); 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the point of this. You have a controller action which receives user input that you are manually rectifying if not valid and willing to test afterwards whether the model is valid or not. If you have manually rectified it why are you testing once again? You know it will be valid, don't you? What's the point of writing a validation rule that you are overriding?

Also note that everything that you rectify at hand in a POST controller action (like updating a model property) should be followed by a `ModelState.Remove("TheKeyOfThePropertyYouHaveManuallyUpdated")` so that those manual changes have some effect.

Comment: I am not manually rectifying the inputted data. I am adding additional data that makes my object valid.

Comment: @B Z, what you are doing is against good practices. You should be using view models and a mapping layer which will map between the view model received by the user and the corresponding model that you will pass to the service layer. So your controller action should take a view model as input parameter and after you ensure that the ModelState is valid it means that the first level of validation passed (things like required fields, formats, ...). Next you map to your business model and pass to the service layer. It's the service layer to report any business errors in the model.

Comment: For example my object has a child collection. My business rule says at least one item must be in this child collection. However this is not entered by the user...the specific business domain is somewhat difficult to explain. If you want additional information I will think of a simpler scenario...

Comment: @B Z, if something is not part of the form that the user submits this something has nothing to do in your view model (the class that your controller action takes as parameter). All your problems stem from the fact that you are trying to use your business models as view models. I can tell you that you are engaging yourself in a war that you are destined to lose. So view models are the way to win it.

Comment: @Darin, we have different views on best practices :) I am aware you encourage use of ViewModels / Domain Services. I model by business objects after uses cases. Not much different than what Rocky Lhotka does with CSLA. Regardless of design practices, the question remains. Is there a way to re-run / reset the ModelState.

Comment: @B Z, as I said in my answer you could clear the properties in the ModelState by using `ModelState.Remove`. Once you remove the corresponding property from the model state it will also remove the corresponding errors. But if you do this I want to emphasize that this is in violation of any good practices and you are doing it at your own risk. I insist: not something I recommend.

Comment: @Darin, I will give that a try, hadn't noticed your updated answer...I just want to re-rerun the rules and have the model state reflect that. I don't think that is a horrible thing :)

Comment: @B Z, not using view models is horrible. Believe me. I just insist so that if other people are reading this are well aware. If you use view models you don't have to rerun anything. The application will follow its natural flow. What you are trying to do now is fighting against the way MVC is supposed to be.

Comment: This model is specific to this use case, so it is not much different than a ViewModel, the difference is in name. I want my Model to have the validation / business logic concerned with this use case. I know you and others encourage to separate the "validation code" (in the ViewModel) from the "business logic" (in service). I believe it should all be in the same domain class.

Comment: @B Z, then all I can wish you is good luck in this difficult endeavor. I am afraid that this won't be the first difficulty you will encounter by not using view models. Of course the choice is yours and you shouldn't in any case be influenced by other people's opinions. Everyone has his own vision and I appreciate yours. I have expressed mine. End of the story.

Comment: @Darin, well said, and I do appreciate your input :) Since I know you've recommended FluentValidation, you may be interested in pocking around the CSLA source. It has the best rules engine I've seen, if anything you may gain some insite into other rules engines :)

Comment: Darin thanks for sharing your approach, I'm using it and I found it usefull